# Micronaut Websocket connection timing out after every 5 minutes

Tags: websocket, netty, micronaut

In my micronaut application I am using websockets but socket connection is timing out after every 5 minutes i want to customize this value.
In micronaut documentation this configuration is given:

```
micronaut:
    server:
        idle-timeout: 30m # 30 minutes
```

But this config is also not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to use this configuration:

```yaml
server:
    idle-timeout: 60m
    read-idle-timeout: 60m
    write-idle-timeout: 60m
```

Turns out Micronaut sends a disconnect event for every one of these settings so we have to update timeout for all three values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the server config would affect every connection you open - not just the socket TCP. The solution for me was to implement a "ping-pong" or "heartbeat" feature - basically a message send from the client to the server and back over a fixed interval. I would send "ping" every `x` minutes and the back end would respond with "pong". Although this does the job at keeping the connection open, I'm certain it's not a good solution for every project.

Also, the documentation [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#websocket) under `Connection Timeouts` section says:"*...By default Micronaut will timeout idle connections that have no activity after 5 minutes. Normally this is not a problem as browsers will automatically reconnect WebSocket sessions...*", which was not the case for me as well.